# How to send emails with TinyMCE editor

Tags: forms, mailto, enctype

I was trying to send an email using the HTML form:

```
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="mailto:someone@$nailmail.com" ENCTYPE="text/plain">
```

In my default email message box, I keep getting the whole HTML code instead of the actual text from the edit box. How can I send only the written,v isible text instead of the whole HTML code from the edit box?  I already tried `ENCTYPE="text/html"`, but that doesn't work.